HTML Bundler Webpack Plugin: Source Tag Error
I am working on a photography portfolio website that I was originally building with the HTML Webpack Plugin, but recently decided to attempt to rebuild it with the newer HTML Bundler Webpack Plugin.
I've managed to figure out and debug a lot of the initial errors I encountered, and three of my pages (homepage, about page, and contact page) have no problems. However, I'm receiving an error message on my webpack build for my three gallery pages, which are all generating essentially the same error message. I will use the gallery of insect photos as an example in this post.
The gallery is a basic photo slider, and each slide is made of a <picture> element so that I can have multiple source images for different device sizes. There is a landscape version and portrait version of the gallery, and the JS controls which one displays based on screen orientation.
When I was using the HTML Webpack Plugin, my syntax for the <picture> elements was not generating an error, and I have already looked at the MDN docs for the <picture> element to confirm that my syntax is correct.
Now, with the HTML Bundler Webpack Plugin I am receiving an error and I don't know why because I know my syntax is correct. I assume this error has something to do with my webpack.config that I can't figure out, rather than the syntax of the <picture> element itself.
The error I am receiving is in relation to the source tag, which I assume is referring to a source tag within the picture element, but I am not sure.
I will post the full error below, but the error begins with the text:

Resolving of source files in the template file failed.
File: src/pages/insects-gallery.ejs
Error: The 'source' tag starting at 4714 position is missing the closing '>' char.

I'm stumped by this because each of my source tags have the closing '>' character. I went through and attempted adding another one to each source, just in case, but that obviously didn't solve my problem.
I'm also not sure how to determine where the "4714 position" is to find out where the missing character might be. I assume it's somewhere in the dist bundle, but the files I've looked through don't have line numbers that go that high.
I've looked through the plugin documentation (https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin/blob/master/README.md#loader-option-sources) and it doesn't seem like I need any special syntax for  or <picture> elements. I'm not having problems with any of the  elements I've used, it's only this mystery closing '>' character at the end of a source (presumably in a <picture> element).
Just to be safe, I uninstalled the HTML Webpack Plugin that I used originally, just in case it was interfering with the Bundler Plugin, but that didn't change anything.
I've been trying to solve this for two days and I'm completely stuck on what to do next. I've spent a lot of time googling around but I haven't seen anything come up that's similar to my problem. Has anyone encountered this before?
See below for my .ejs file, the full error, and my webpack.config. Please let me know if anything else would be useful to see.
EJS (showing the portrait gallery to demonstrate document structure, but removed the landscape gallery to avoid going over this post's character limit):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../index.js" defer="defer"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header class="header header-border">
        <nav>
          <ul class="menu-items" id="tabs">
            <li class="menu-btn hov-style" data-name="index">
              <a aria-label="Home Page" href="../dist/index.html">Home</a>
            </li>

            <div
              class="dropdown-div menu-btn gal-hov dropdown-btn"
              data-name="galleries"
              title="Galleries"
            >
              <div class="gal-btn-div">
                <li aria-label="Click to Open Submenu">
                  <a class="gals-link" href="#galleries">Galleries</a>
                </li>

                <div class="gal-arrow"></div>
              </div>

              <ul class="dropdown-content">
                <li
                  class="dropdown-item birds"
                  style="--delay: 1"
                  data-name="birds-gallery"
                  aria-label="Click to Visit Gallery"
                >
                  <a href="../dist/birds-gallery.html">Birds</a>
                </li>
                <li
                  class="dropdown-item insects"
                  style="--delay: 2"
                  data-name="insects-gallery"
                  aria-label="Click to Visit Gallery"
                >
                  <a href="../dist/insects-gallery.html">Insects</a>
                </li>
                <li
                  class="dropdown-item small-animals"
                  style="--delay: 3"
                  data-name="small-animals-gallery"
                  aria-label="Click to Visit Gallery"
                >
                  <a href="../dist/small-animals-gallery.html">Small Animals</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

            <li class="menu-btn hov-style" data-name="about">
              <a aria-label="About Page" href="../dist/about.html">About</a>
            </li>

            <li class="menu-btn hov-style" data-name="contact">
              <a aria-label="Contact Page" href="../dist/contact.html"
                >Contact</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <main class="main gal-main" data-name="insects-gallery">
        <!-- INSECTS GALLERY -->
        <section class="tab-content gal-portrait" id="insects-gallery">
          <div class="gallery portrait-gallery">
            <div class="animation-ctrl-div portrait-animation-ctrl-div">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="pause-btn portrait-pause-btn"
                title="Press Enter or Space to Pause Gallery Animation"
              >
                <img
                  class="pause-icon portrait-pause-icon"
                  src="../assets/imgs/pause-button-icon.svg"
                  alt="Press Enter or Space to Pause Gallery Animation"
                />
              </button>

              <button
                type="button"
                class="play-btn portrait-play-btn"
                title="Press Enter or Space to Start Gallery Animation"
              >
                <img
                  class="play-icon portrait-play-icon"
                  src="../assets/imgs/play-button-icon.svg"
                  title="Start Gallery Animation"
                  alt="Press Enter or Space to Start Gallery Animation"
                />
              </button>
            </div>

            <section
              class="slider-box portrait-slider-box"
              tabindex="0"
              role="region"
              aria-roledescription="photo slider"
              aria-label="Insects Gallery"
            >
              <!-- <div class="slider-row-one"></div> -->
              <button type="button" class="back-arrow" data-back-arrow>
                <img
                  data-icon-back
                  class="arrow"
                  src="../assets/imgs/reshot-icon-arrow-chevron-left-975UQXVKZF.svg"
                  alt="Back Arrow"
                />
              </button>

              <div class="photo-box portrait-photo-box">
                <!-- BEE ON SAGE FLOWER -->
                <picture
                  class="picture"
                  aria-role="group"
                  aria-roledescription="slide"
                  aria-labelledby="slide1"
                  tabindex="0"
                >
                  <source
                    media="(300px <= width <=699px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.06.09_bee-vertical-320p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <source
                    media="(700px <= width <= 799px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.06.09_bee-vertical-460p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <source
                    media="(800px <= width <= 1020px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.06.09_bee-vertical-580p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <img
                    src="../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.06.09_bee-vertical-700p.jpg"
                    alt="Slide 1 of 6: A bee sitting on a purple sage flower with its arms over its head, as if about to thrust its arms forward onto the flower."
                    id="slide1"
                  />
                </picture>

                <!-- CATERPILLAR -->
                <picture
                  class="picture"
                  role="group"
                  aria-roledescription="slide"
                  aria-labelledby="slide2"
                  tabindex="0"
                >
                  <source
                    media="(300px <= width <= 699px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.09.05_caterpillar-vertical-320p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <source
                    media="(700px <= width <= 799px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.09.05_caterpillar-vertical-460p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <source
                    media="(800px <= width <= 1020px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.09.05_caterpillar-vertical-580p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <img
                    src="../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.09.05_caterpillar-vertical-700p.jpg"
                    alt="Slide 2 of 6: A close up of a swallowtail butterfly caterpillar crawling vertically up a fennel stalk. The caterpillar is green with black stripes and yellow dots on every other stripe."
                    id="slide2"
                  />
                </picture>

                <!-- DRAGONFLY -->
                <picture
                  class="picture"
                  role="group"
                  aria-roledescription="slide"
                  aria-labelledby="slide3"
                  tabindex="0"
                >
                  <source
                    media="(300px <= width <= 699px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.08.02_dragonfly-vertical-320p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <source
                    media="(700px <= width <= 799px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.08.02_dragonfly-vertical-460p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <source
                    media="(800px <= width <= 1020px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.08.02_dragonfly-vertical-580p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <img
                    src="../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.08.02_dragonfly-vertical-700p.jpg"
                    alt="Slide 3 of 6: An eastern amberwing dragonfly sits on the branch of a cotoneaster plant, facing right in the frame and glancing toward the camera."
                    id="slide3"
                  />
                </picture>

                <!-- ANT -->
                <picture
                  class="picture"
                  role="group"
                  aria-roledescription="slide"
                  aria-labelledby="slide4"
                  tabindex="0"
                >
                  <source
                    media="(300px <= width <= 699px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.06.09_ant_leaf-vertical-320p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <source
                    media="(700px <= width <= 799px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.06.09_ant_leaf-vertical-460p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <source
                    media="(800px <= width <= 1020px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.06.09_ant_leaf-vertical-580p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <img
                    src="../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.06.09_ant_leaf-vertical-700p.jpg"
                    alt="Slide 4 of 6: A black ant crawls towad the left side of a large green leaf with serrated edges that is pointing vertically toward the top of the frame. The majority of the frame is filled with light and dark green leaves from the same plant."
                    id="slide4"
                  />
                </picture>

                <!-- BUTTERFLY -->
                <picture
                  class="picture"
                  role="group"
                  aria-roledescription="slide"
                  aria-labelledby="slide5"
                  tabindex="0"
                >
                  <source
                    media="(300px <= width <= 699px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.08.09_butterfly-vertical-320p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <source
                    media="(700px <= width <= 799px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.08.09_butterfly-vertical-460p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <source
                    media="(800px <= width <= 1020px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.08.09_butterfly-vertical-580p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <img
                    src="../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.08.09_butterfly-vertical-700p.jpg"
                    alt="Slide 5 of 6: A bright yellow eastern tiger swallowtail butterfly with black stripes sits on top of a purple thistle flower."
                    id="slide5"
                  />
                </picture>

                <!-- GRASSHOPPER -->
                <picture
                  class="picture"
                  role="group"
                  aria-roledescription="slide"
                  aria-labelledby="slide6"
                  tabindex="0"
                >
                  <source
                    media="(300px <= width <= 699px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.08.26_grasshopper-vertical-320p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <source
                    media="(700px <= width <= 799px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.08.26_grasshopper-vertical-460p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <source
                    media="(800px <= width <= 1020px) and (orientation: portrait)"
                    srcset="
                      ../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.08.26_grasshopper-vertical-580p.jpg
                    "
                  />

                  <img
                    src="../assets/imgs/insects-gal/Guneratne_2023.08.26_grasshopper-vertical-700p.jpg"
                    alt="Slide 6 of 6: A closeup of a grasshopper sitting on a serrated leaf facing upward toward the right at a diagonal angle in the frame."
                    id="slide6"
                  />
                </picture>
              </div>

              <button type="button" class="forward-arrow" data-forward-arrow>
                <img
                  data-icon-forward
                  class="arrow"
                  src="../assets/imgs/reshot-icon-arrow-chevron-right-WDGHUKQ634.svg"
                  alt="Forward Arrow"
                />
              </button>

              <div class="img-dots-container">
                <div class="img-dots">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="circle-icon-div"
                    data-circle="0"
                    aria-label="Select Slide 1 of 6."
                  >
                    <div class="circle-icon" data-circle="0"></div>
                  </button>

                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="circle-icon-div"
                    data-circle="1"
                    aria-label="Select Slide 2 of 6."
                  >
                    <div class="circle-icon" data-circle="1"></div>
                  </button>

                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="circle-icon-div"
                    data-circle="2"
                    aria-label="Select Slide 3 of 6."
                  >
                    <div class="circle-icon" data-circle="2"></div>
                  </button>

                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="circle-icon-div"
                    data-circle="3"
                    aria-label="Select Slide 4 of 6."
                  >
                    <div class="circle-icon" data-circle="3"></div>
                  </button>

                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="circle-icon-div"
                    data-circle="4"
                    aria-label="Select Slide 5 of 6."
                  >
                    <div class="circle-icon" data-circle="4"></div>
                  </button>

                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="circle-icon-div"
                    data-circle="5"
                    aria-label="Select Slide 6 of 6."
                  >
                    <div class="circle-icon" data-circle="5"></div>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
      <footer class="footer-div"></footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

Full Error:

LoaderException:
HTML Bundler Plugin  Resolving of source files in the template file failed.
File: src/pages/insects-gallery.ejs
Error: The 'source' tag starting at 4714 position is missing the closing '>' char.
at HtmlParser.parseTag (/Users/jguneratne/repos/photo-gallery/node_modules/html-bundler-webpack-plugin/src/Common/HtmlParser.js:174:15)
at Template.resolve (/Users/jguneratne/repos/photo-gallery/node_modules/html-bundler-webpack-plugin/src/Loader/Template.js:26:37)
at /Users/jguneratne/repos/photo-gallery/node_modules/html-bundler-webpack-plugin/src/Loader/index.js:97:23
at resolveError (/Users/jguneratne/repos/photo-gallery/node_modules/html-bundler-webpack-plugin/src/Loader/Messages/Exeptions.js:187:10)
at /Users/jguneratne/repos/photo-gallery/node_modules/html-bundler-webpack-plugin/src/Loader/index.js:122:19

Webpack.config:
const path = require("path");
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require("html-bundler-webpack-plugin");
const ejs = require("ejs");

// create EJS config
const ejsConfig = {
  root: process.cwd(), // define root template path when using `include()`
  async: true, // optional, async rendering
};

module.exports = {
  stats: { children: true },
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist/"),
    clean: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@scripts": path.join(__dirname, "src/js"),
      "@styles": path.join(__dirname, "src/css"),
      "@images": path.join(__dirname, "src/images"),
    },
  },

  devtool: "inline-source-map",

  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      entry: [
        {
          import: "./src/pages/template.ejs", // template file
          filename: "index.html", // => dist/index.html
          data: { title: "Bosco Images Wildlife Photography: Homepage" }, // pass variables into template
        },
        {
          import: "./src/pages/galleries.ejs",
          filename: "galleries.html",
          data: { title: "Bosco Images Wildlife Photography: Photo Galleries" },
        },
        {
          import: "./src/pages/birds-gallery.ejs",
          filename: "birds-gallery.html",
          data: { title: "Bosco Images Wildlife Photography: Birds Gallery" },
        },
        {
          import: "./src/pages/insects-gallery.ejs",
          filename: "insects-gallery.html",
          data: {
            title: "Bosco Images Wildlife Photography: Insects Gallery",
          },
        },
        {
          import: "./src/pages/small-animals-gallery.ejs",
          filename: "small-animals-gallery.html",
          data: {
            title: "Bosco Images Wildlife Photography: Small Animals Gallery",
          },
        },
        {
          import: "./src/pages/about.ejs",
          filename: "about.html",
          data: { title: "About: Bosco Images Wildlife Photography" },
        },
        {
          import: "./src/pages/contact.ejs",
          filename: "contact.html",
          data: { title: "Contact: Bosco Images Wildlife Photography" },
        },
      ],
      js: {
        // output filename for JS
        filename: "js/[name].[contenthash:8].js",
      },
      css: {
        // output filename for CSS
        filename: "css/[name].[contenthash:8].css",
      },
      preprocessor: "ejs",
    }),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(html|ejs)$/,
        loader: HtmlBundlerPlugin.loader,
        options: {
          preprocessor: (template, { data }) =>
            ejs.render(template, data, ejsConfig), // <= use EJS compiler
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              import: false, // disable @import at-rules handling
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|ico|svg)$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: "assets/imgs/[name].[hash:8][ext]",
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  //enable HMR with live reload
  devServer: {
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    watchFiles: {
      paths: ["src/**/*.*"],
      options: {
        usePolling: true,
      },
    },
  },
};


Please, create an issue with a small reproducible repo directly in GitHub: https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin/issues
I will help you.

I can reproduce the issue. It is a bug in the plugin. I will fix it.

currently, the plugin doesn't support the new range syntax in Media Queries Level 4.
I will add supporting for this new syntax in the next version.
Alternate, you can use the standard media syntax with min-width and max-width.

Thank you SO much - this solution fixed the problem. I'm glad I asked, I never would have thought to try this.
